# Excel formatting my dates when I don't want it to?

Tags: excel-interop

I'm using excel interop to build reports. I have the string "April 8, 2013" as a string and I'm assigning it to a cell as such (where oSheet is an `Excel._Worksheet` and it's VB.Net):

```
oSheet.Cells(5, 2) = dateStr;
```

Nothing is modifying the `NumberFormat` or any other properties for that particular cell but what is being displayed when I open the output xlsx file is "8-Apr-13".

How can I force excel to just display the string without any additional formatting that might change the text?

Comment: Set the NumberFormat to "Text" explicitly first, or put an apostrophe / single quote ( ' ) in front of the string.

Comment: "Text" didn't quite work, it put in "T2013xt". But adding a single quote before the dates worked great.

Comment: Yeah, I realized later that you set the number format by: `range.NumberFormat = "@";` for text.

Comment: You should put those both (the `@` and the `'`) down as an answer. They both worked for me although I'm sticking with the `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force Excel to treat a date, or any non-textual data, as text, and thus not changing it's format automatically, you can use either of the following two methods:

- Precede the date with a single quote, e.g. `'08/01/2013`
- Set the NumberFormat of the range to Text with `range.NumberFormat = "@";`